# How do I make a DIV set to style.display = "none" by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hidden

I'm trying to make a button that will display additional text when it's hit, however, I can only make it either

- a) display the text by default or
- b) hide the text by default but the button doesn't work.

Here's the JS code for the button:

```js
function showInfo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myDIV">
 Hello World
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" click="showInfo()">
Show Info
</button>
```

Is there a way I can set the default style.display to none?

Comment: CSS `#myDiv { display: none; }` will set the element as hidden "by default." Or just put it on the element inline like `<div style="display:none;"></div>`

Comment: @daddygames Thank you! This worked for me!

Comment: if it is about js only : `window.onload=showInfo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler is `click`. It needs to be `onclick`. Also, I recommend either adding a class with `display:none` to your `div`, or simply inlining it, like this:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none">
 Hello World
</div>
<button onclick="showInfo()">
Show Info
</button>
```

Then your JS can look like this:

```
function showInfo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    return x.style.display = "block";
  }
  return x.style.display = "none";
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function showInfo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    return x.style.display = "block";
  }
  return x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="myDIV" style="display: none">
     Hello World
    </div>
    <button onclick="showInfo()">
    Show Info
    </button>
```

Comment: if it is about js only : `window.onload=showInfo();` would do the job too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS to set the default style for any element – either by linking to an external CSS file or in-between the opening and closing `<style>` tags in your HTML file.

**Like so**

```css
#myDIV {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no issue with your JS code.

Instead

Do correct your HTML, it is 'onclick' rather than just 'click'

```
<button onclick="showInfo()">
```