# Using Javascript to toggle reveal content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use Javascript to reveal additional content by clicking a button.
I've found a script that hides content OnClick, how would I reverse this so it instead reveals content OnClick?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <div id="myDIV">This is my DIV element. </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ns7u24of/1/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a DIV set to style.display = "none" by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275372/how-do-i-make-a-div-set-to-style-display-none-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize the div with `display: none;` and reverse the `if/else`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  console.log(x.style.display);
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't have to reverse if/else

Comment: If he doesn't reverse it he would need to click twice for make the div appear for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `display: none` to your css, so it won't be displayed initially.